# How to rewrite url in htaccess to make user freindly url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site in wordpress in which a page is showing questions based on its `ID`.

```
http://example.com/index.php/question/?questionid=9&title='how-to-rewite-htaccess'
```

I am the beginner to php I'm not able to graps other examples found on stackoverflow.com

Here's my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/question/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /question/?questionid=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

But this is not working. please tell where is error.

Comment: Please post an error message so we know what is wrong.

Comment: there is no error message when type http://example.com/index.php/question/9/how-to-rewite-htaccess/ then go to 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

Since your using Wordpress you can turn on permalinks which takes care of the url friendly urls for you see https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen.

Login to your admin then go to permalinks and set a preferred style.

Answer (score 1):

`example.com/index.php/question/9/how-to-rewite-htaccess` doesn't match your rewrite rule because the rule has a trailing `/`.  Change the regex (first) part of your rewrite rule to:

```
^/question/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$
```

Adding `?` makes the trailing `/` optional.

Answer (score 0):

Once you go to **setting > permalinks** and set the pretty links, WordPress will automatically generate .htaccess based on the setting you choose. Don't forget to save.

More information here http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-you-cant-find-htaccess-file-on-your-wordpress-site/